# ASP.net application do I need to upload .cs and .designer.cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my ASP.net application do I need to upload the .cs and .designer.cs files to the server with the compiled application?

Comment: published, no. compiled/built, yes

Comment: What is the difference between published and compiled?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.80).aspx about half way down.

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory - that link describes what happens when you build or publish. It mentions nothing about whether you 'need to upload .cs and .designer.cs files'. You do not have to upload those files.

Comment: @Kirk, thank you for your critic. But that link was to show how and what a published website was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. If you do a "publish", your application will runs perfectly only with the ASPXs and DLLs genrated by the publishing.